# What does actionURL tag do in Liferay?

Tags: java, jsp, tags, liferay

What does the following code do in Liferay portlet JSP:

```
<portlet:actionURL var="editPromotionURL">
    <portlet:param name="mvcPath" value="/edit.jsp" />
</portlet:actionURL>
```

According to `com.liferay.taglib.portlet.ActionURLTag` source code I deduced that this tag creates `LiferayPortletURL` from given parameters and put it's textual representation into `var` named variable. Is this correct?

I can't find where `mvcPath` parameter is used. What is it's function?

How can the result of this tag be used with `<aui:form action="<%=editPromotionURL%>" method="post">`? I thought JSP expression doesn't read `pageContext`. Isn't it correct to write `${editPromotionURL}`? How former can work?

Are the any other functions of actionURL tag?

What if there are both `portlet:actionURL` and `portlet:renderURL` tags in JSP?

Answer (score 6):

There are 2 things at play here.

#### Rendering JSPs

First, the mvcPath parameter is typically used when you create a Portlet class extending\using Liferay's `com.liferay.util.bridges.mvc.MVCPortlet`.

When you create a renderURL, you can use the `mvcPath` parameter to tell the MVCPortlet to render a particular JSP.

The usage is as follows:

```
<portlet:renderURL var="viewEditPromotionURL">
    <portlet:param name="mvcPath" value="/edit.jsp" />
</portlet:renderURL>

<a href="<%= viewEditPromotionURL %>">Edit Promo</a>
```

#### Posting Form Data

You can also use the `MVCPortlet` to handle POSTed data.

```
<portlet:actionURL name="editPromotion" var="editPromotionURL" />

<form action="<%= editPromotionURL %>" method="post"></form>
```

As you can see `mvcPath` the parameter is not necessary. Instead by including the `name` attribute you tell the MVCPortlet class to look for a method named after this attribute. In our case: `editPromotion`.

Inside your portlet class, as long as you've extended `MVCPortlet`, all you need to do is to implement this method and use the `actionRequest` to get any POSTed data you might need.

```
public void editPromotion(
        ActionRequest actionRequest, ActionResponse actionResponse)
    throws PortalException, SystemException {
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But how one can use `<%= viewEditPromotionURL>`? I am using `${viewEditPromotionURL}` in the case and it works. I was thinking that for former work it should be java variable in translated servlet code, not key-value pair... Isn't it true?

Comment: Hi Dims, its a bug... it should be `<%= myVar %>` not `<%= myVar >`